# My API works fine without passport.authenticate but with it, it gives an error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mern, passport-jwt

I'm new to web development and I have been working on a project, I'm using the mern stack here but I have encountered a problem that I have been trying to solve here is a screenshot of the get request I'm sending when I use passport.authenticate I get this error but when I remove it from the get request the API works fine ! how can I make it work with the authentication! 
thanks in advance for anybody who is willing to help!
I really appreciate it!

```
//get all client (private route)
router.get('/clients', passport.authenticate('managerauth', { session: false }),  (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};


  Client.find({}, { username: 1, _id: 0 })
    .then(clients => {
      if (!clients) {
        errors.noclients = 'No clients available';
        return res.status(404).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(clients);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));

});
```

Comment: What exactly is this subroutine trying to do?

Comment: Im  trying to get all the clients in the Clients collection @KaseyChang

Comment: It works fine when i remove  passport.authenticate('managerauth', { session: false })

Comment: And what is this "managerAuth"?  I do believe you are supposed to pass in a passport-strategy there as per passport.js specs. 

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Comment: Mangerauth is my strategy i created 2 different strategies one for client apis and the other for manger apis i teststed both an they are working fine but this route with this query gives me an error if i remove the query and but a simple res.json in the route it works if i remove the passport authentication from the route and leave the query in the route the query is displayed @Kasy Chang ☹️

Comment: Temporarily replace the strategy with a known strategy like "local" or "basic" to make absolutely sure it is not your ManangeAuth that is the problem. If your code works with basic or local strategy, then the failure point is your ManageAuth strategy.